# Django customizing widget to CharField breaks

Tags: django, django-forms

According to the docs, you should be able to add a "widgets" dictionary and overwrite individual widgets.
However this gets me the error `'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'`. Note that the name is a TextField but I would like the widget to be a CharField. Shouldn't this work according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)?

In my models.py

```py
    class Todo(TimeStampedModel):
        name = models.TextField()
        notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
        url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

In my views.py

```py
    class TodoCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Todo
            fields = ['name', 'notes', 'url']
            widgets = {
                'name': forms.CharField()
            }
```

I realize I can manually declare `name = forms.CharField()` but the pattern above seems to follow the docs and should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CharField is not a widget - it is a form field
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#module-django.forms.widgets (Note first tip)

You might be able to use the TextInput widget though: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput

```
widgets = {
    'name': forms.TextInput()
}
```

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. I wish this comment was the error message

Comment: is there a mapping of form fields to widgets somewhere? I know there is this list of widgets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-handling-input-of-text but I havent found a one to one mapping